# Lucee Soap 400 Error; works fine as-is in CF

Tags: soap, cfml, lucee

I am trying to perform a CFHTTP call using Lucee 4.5. Test code on my main workstation is ok (running CF 10), but when copied exactly to a laptop with Lucee if fails with **400 error invalid headers sent**. See below

```
#XML Being Passed
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <m:Authenticate xmlns:m="http://foo.com/2005/">     
      <m:userName>xxxxx</m:userName>
      <m:password>xxxxx</m:password>
    </m:Authenticate>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>


#Partial Codebase; 'variable' is XML posted above
<cfhttp url="http://xxxxxxx?WSDL" method="post" result="theCFHTTP" compression="false">
            <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Content-Type" value="text/xml; charset=utf-8">
            <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Accept" value="application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*">
            <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="User-Agent" value="Axis/1.1">

            <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache">
            <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Pragma" value="no-cache">
            <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="SOAPAction" value="http://foo.com/2005/Authenticate">
            <cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Content-Length" value="#len(soap)#">
            <cfhttpparam type="xml" name="body" value="#soap#">
        </cfhttp>
```

I am very new to Lucee and never used Railo so if there are unique charsets or other configuration options that need to be done I'd appreciate the help.

**Edit**: Further tests have determined that I cannot CFHTTP to any page outside of the laptop itself. All external URLs give a 400 bad header message.

I also added `compression=false` so that Lucee would not auto send GZip content to the request url.

My working machine's return headers:

- **Charset**: utf-8
- **Header**: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 14:58:03 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 603
- **Mimetype**: text/xml

The failing machine's return headers:

- **Charset**: us-ascii
- **Header**: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 15:06:18 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 339
- **Mimetype**: text/html

**MAY 19 EDIT:**

I tested each of the following adjustments separately within the CFHTTP call based on Fabio's response:

1. I removed the Content-Type header param, or
2. Changed the body param from 'xml' to 'body'

Neither worked, though my error message has changed to **400 Bad Request**. A dump of the CFHTTP call says I am sending invalid XML though independent checks verify it is, in fact, valid. It's failing at the token authentication call.

Comment: Since you have one that works and one that doesn't. I would fire up your network monitoring tool (browser tools can do this too) and compare the headers being sent from the working server and non working server. Then report back on what you see and we'll go from there.

Comment: I added your request.

Comment: We are more interested in the request headers since those presumably are the ones causing the issue. Can you compare those and include what you find. Also is there a firewall, proxy server, or anything else between the failing machine and the internet? Are you able to browse to the web site on that same machine using a browser?

Comment: There is no firewall or proxy (the SOAP request works from my personal laptop), The website I am calling does exist when viewed in a browser. I will try to get the request headers.

Comment: It did not work. Please see my edited post.

Comment: @AngrySpartan did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No. Unfortunately the project was sidelined and haven't been able to return.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. Finally, I got it!

I sniffed network traffic using tcpdump and It looked like our request to IIS7 contained the *Content-Type* header twice, thus resulting in the ugly

> Bad Request - Invalid Header Name error

The problem is in the body parameter:

```
<cfhttpparam type="xml" name="body" value="#soap#">
```

Lucee sets the Content-Type header accordingly, to text/xml; utf-8... then sets it once again based on your other parameter:

```
<cfhttpparam type="HEADER" name="Content-Type" value="text/xml; charset=utf-8">
```

You have two choices:

1. leave type="xml" to your cfhttpparam tag, and remove the explicit MIME+charset param
2. change type="xml" to **type="body"** and manually set all of your headers

Comment: What would I change if I manually had to set my headers? I'm already specifying them, no?

Comment: That's right, I also needed to set them manually. Just don't do it twice: change type=XML to type=BODY and you're done.

Comment: Fabio dude, you son of a gun saved me a ton of work!!! how can one assume that type="xml" sets the Content-Type header as well... thank you so much!